# InsertAdjacentHTML gets overridden by HTML on page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a browser extension and I've made it open a modal when I click on text on any webpage.

I used `insertAdjacentHTML` and for some reason any time I click to open the modal it uses the styling of the webpage/website I'm on rather than the styling that I gave it in the CSS file.

How can I get my CSS to rather override so that I keep my styling?

Where I *believe* the problem is happening:

```js
// On mouse click
allText[i].addEventListener('click', async () => {
  // Load in HTML file
  fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL(findFontModal))
    .then(r => r.text())
    .then(html => {
      allText[i].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
    });
});
```

Full js code:

```js
// Receiving message from popup.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.switchStatus === "on") {
      // Getting all text elements
      const allText = document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p, li, td, caption, span, a');
      const colors = ['#ffadad', '#ffd6a5', '#fdffb6', '#caffbf', '#bdb2ff', '#9fdfff'];
      const findFontModal = 'findfont.html'

      // Loop through all text elements-
      // to be able to manipulate each individual one
      for (let i = 0; i < allText.length; i++) {
        // On hover
        allText[i].addEventListener('mouseover', async () => {
          allText[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
          allText[i].style.cursor = "pointer";
        });

        allText[i].addEventListener('mouseout', async () => {
          allText[i].style.backgroundColor = null;
        });

        // On mouse click
        allText[i].addEventListener('click', async () => {
          // Load in HTML file
          fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL(findFontModal))
            .then(r => r.text())
            .then(html => {
              allText[i].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
            });
        })
      }

      sendResponse({ status: "done" });
    }

    // When toggle switch is unchecked
    else if (request.switchStatus === "off") {
      const allText = document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p, li, td, caption, span, a');
      for (let i = 0; i < allText.length; i++) {
        allText[i].style.backgroundColor = null;
      }

      sendResponse({ status: "done" });
    }
  }
);
```

**Modal HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="content.css">
    <title>Find Font Modal</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="modal-div">
        <div class="titlebar">
            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="main-content">
            <div class="names">
                <h1>Font Name</h1>
                <h5>Foundry Name</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="font-props">
                <div class="color-div">
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <h4>#000000</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="actual-props">
                    <div class="column-1">
                        <h4>Font Weight</h4>
                        <h3>Blank</h3>

                        <h4 class="second">Line Height</h4>
                        <h3>Blank</h3>
                    </div>

                    <div class="column-2">
                        <h4>Font Size</h4>
                        <h3>Blank</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="buttons">
                <button class="tryfont-btn">Try out this font</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7ad5f72cd3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Code on Github: https://github.com/JojoDuke/fs-extension-core

Comment: Are you trying to insert a modal into a h1,h2... ?!

Comment: No not inserting. Just making it appear/pop up when any text element is clicked. Is my approach wrong or?

Comment: No, but why not just get data then append them to modal already present in html before ?Can you put your modal html here please ?

Comment: Ok, the modal html has been added. With appendChild I'd have to add each element one by one right? and that would be tedious/confusing, so I decided to use this method to load in the whole HTML file. If there's a better method, please lemme know :0

Comment: Remove everything else than you `.modal-div` (and content), you don't have to redelcare all html in your modal because you append it to body. But a proper way to do what you  want is to put your div in your parent document, then toggle visible/hidden on demand

Comment: Sorry to ask but I don't really get you...how would this be done??

Comment: Put your modal in your main HTML document, add css `display:none` to it, then use `document.querySelector('.modal-div').styles.display = 'block/none'` to toggle

Comment: Ohh, the thing is there is no main HTML, I'm using the content.js script so any HTML I want to add I'd have to add it directly to the page through the script, there is no index.html or such...

Comment: So, remove your html, body, etc keep only div.modal-div et add <style></style> directly on your modal html then test and tell me.

Comment: Still not getting it. Isn't there anyway to just override the CSS on the page with mine?

Comment: If you use `document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<style>*{backgroud:red}</style>')` what append ? Normaly everything must be red, if not, means you can't.

Comment: This does work. But what happens is that the design in the modal gets broken and uses the style of the text/page
Heres what I'm talking about: https://imgur.com/a/hefYbpV

Comment: Try with `!important`, on your h2,h2,etc element

Comment: Yeah, even `!important` isn't helping too much...

Comment: Put you css inline...

Comment: Ok, it seems like inline CSS is working, but some of the styling can't be completely done. Like for example, I can't find a way to add custom fonts now...

Comment: Load your font with import inline css ?

Comment: Thats not working

Comment: What did your Browser Developper Tool says  ? When you inspect element did the font loaded ?

Comment: It's so strange, every page renders the CSS differently, it makes no sense....

Comment: As is, without your entire code i can't help more, sorry.

Comment: How can I send you my entire code please?

Comment: https://github.com

Comment: Heres what I've been able to hack up so far: https://github.com/JojoDuke/fs-extension-core

Answer (score 0):

Use `classes` and `IDs` that are unique to your extension..
all `querySelectors` you are working with, and the modal's HTML should have class names and IDs all with lets say a prefix of the name of your extension..

like `class="modal-div"` would be something like: `class="_my_extension_modal-div"`, and so on. This way you would not overlap with any website's classes/IDs.

---

Another hack is to add `!important` to your CSS, but this might not work, or might brake the actual website when viewing it with your extension enabled.

Comment: This will not resolve the issue for these two scenarios (1) css can be applied by tag name and are cascading meaning modal will inherit any styles left unspecified (2) web app may load styles dynamically with !important, after the extension styles have loaded, which could realistically occur for single-page apps. Doing a find font modal is likely for all domains, so any style configuration could occur, and needs to be overwritten.